# Python: Scale each row of 2d array to values that sum to 1. Each row contains some negative values

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, probability

Let's say I have an array:

```
myArray = [[-1.58, -1.09, -0.41,  0.22, -0.95],
          [-1.16, -1.27, -1.89, -1.01,  1.11],
          [-0.73, -0.81, -0.47, -0.46, -0.04],
          [-1.46, -0.82,  0.40, -0.22, -1.82],
          [-1.12 , -0.97, -0.89, -0.18,  0.06]]
```

I wish to convert each line of this array into values that sum to 1 for each row.

Is this easily possible?

My actual array is several thousand lines long, so I would like a solution that optimizes well if possible. Thank you very much!

I realize that I'm not being clear.
I want the resulting values to be **positive** and **sum to 1**. Sorry.

I can give you a sample using positive values (That's total at the end):

Row1    1.10    2.20    3.30    4.40    5.50    (Total = 16.50)

Row2    2.20    3.30    4.40    5.50    6.60    (Total = 22.00)

Row3    4.20    5.01    2.50    3.30    1.10    (Total = 16.11)

to (again total at the end)::

Row1    0.07    0.13    0.20    0.27    0.33    (Total = 1.00)

Row2    0.10    0.15    0.20    0.25    0.30    (Total = 1.00)

Row3    0.26    0.31    0.16    0.20    0.07    (Total = 1.00)

And i achieve this by simply adding a row, then diving each cell in each row by the total of that row. I don't know how to achieve this in python with an array, with negative values.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want, could you provide an example output and some code that you have tried?

Comment: @JoeyPython Is there any relation between Row1 input and Row 1 output?? or they are just random numbers..?

Comment: I think I know what you mean now, you want to add all the values in a row, then change the values to be the percentage they represent in the sum. Like in row1, 1.10 is 0.7 (0.6666 rounded) of the total of the row. The problem is I can't think off the top of my head of a way to integrate negatives into a positive percentage? @JoeyPython

Comment: yes @dhdavvie  that is a good summary of what I'd like to do!

Comment: "I realize that I'm not being clear. I want the resulting values to be positive and sum to zero. Sorry." - You mean "sum to one" here, I presume?

Comment: yes @Andrew sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using min-max normalization to transform original data, this could be one approach:

```
myArray = [[-1.58, -1.09, -0.41, 0.22, -0.95], 
[-1.16, -1.27, -1.89, -1.01, 1.11], 
[-0.73, -0.81, -0.47, -0.46, -0.04], 
[-1.46, -0.82, 0.40, -0.22, -1.82], 
[-1.12 , -0.97, -0.89, -0.18, 0.06]]

#Transform data
normalizedArray = []

for row in range(0, len(myArray)):
    list = []
    Min =  min(myArray[row])
    Max = max(myArray[row])

    for element in myArray[row]:
        list.append(  float(element-Min)/float(Max- Min) )

    normalizedArray.append(list)

#Normalize to 1
newArray = []

for row in range(0, len(normalizedArray)):
    list = [x / sum(normalizedArray[row]) for x in normalizedArray[row]]
    newArray.append(list)
```

Comment: You could also convert the original array to a `numpy` array and call `.sum(axis=1)` on it to give an array of the averages, but I agree, I don't think it's possible to do what the OP wants. If a row has a mix of positive and negative values you'd have to determine the absolute value first and then carry out this operation.

Comment: This is certainly getting close, however i am still getting negative values in the result:         newArray[0:1]
[[0.41469816272965887,
  0.2860892388451444,
  0.10761154855643044,
  -0.05774278215223098,
  0.24934383202099739]]

Comment: Consider unity-based normalization perhaps: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/how-do-i-normalize-an-array-of-positive-and-negative-numbers-so-they-are-between

Comment: Hi @LukeBowl Is there a way of converting: [link](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5888) to python and applying it to an array? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much @LukeBowl !

Answer (score 1):

As I say, I don't think you can achieve exactly what you need (because if you have a mix of positive and negative values, you'll always have a mix of positive and negative values in the ratio of the value to the sum of the row).
But this gets close, I think.

```
import numpy as np

myArray = [[-1.58, -1.09, -0.41, 0.22, -0.95], 
[-1.16, -1.27, -1.89, -1.01, 1.11], 
[-0.73, -0.81, -0.47, -0.46, -0.04], 
[-1.46, -0.82, 0.40, -0.22, -1.82], 
[-1.12 , -0.97, -0.89, -0.18, 0.06]]

new_array = abs(np.asarray(new_array))

ratio_array = np.divide(new_array, new_array.sum(axis=1))
```

EDIT: I've used `%timeit`, and a `numpy` method is 10x faster than the looping method above.

```
new_array = np.asarray(myArray)

transformed_array = new_array + (np.min(new_array, axis=1) * -1)[:, None]

ratio_matrix = transformed_array / np.sum(transformed_array, axis=1)[:, None]
```

Comment: This is getting very close. However can you instead calculate the minimum number on each row (in the case of row 1 it is -1.58) and add that to each element of row 1? That would then ensure that each value in row 1 is now positive. And now calculate the "percentage they represent in the sum" of each row. I think this would be a better result for me, as i want to highlight for instance in the first row, that 0.22 is the max/optimal score.

Comment: I suggest that you play around with the functions that are available (such as min), you should be able to find the solution you need from what I've given you here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're asking for:

```
myArray = [[-1.58, -1.09, -0.41, 0.22, -0.95], 
[-1.16, -1.27, -1.89, -1.01, 1.11], 
[-0.73, -0.81, -0.47, -0.46, -0.04], 
[-1.46, -0.82, 0.40, -0.22, -1.82], 
[-1.12 , -0.97, -0.89, -0.18, 0.06]] 


print [sum(_list) for _list in myArray]
```

?

```
[-3.8099999999999996, -4.219999999999999, -2.51, -3.92, -3.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
data = [[-1.58, -1.09, -0.41, 0.22, -0.95],
        [-1.16, -1.27, -1.89, -1.01, 1.11],
        [-0.73, -0.81, -0.47, -0.46, -0.04],
        [-1.46, -0.82, 0.40, -0.22, -1.82],
        [-1.12, -0.97, -0.89, -0.18, 0.06]]


print[[x / sum(data[r]) for x in data[r]] for r in range(0, len(data))]
```